# Are shared library pages anonymous?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

From my understanding, memory mapped pages are pages that are backed by files whereas anonumous pages are pages that are allocated without a file or device backing them. According to this definition, memory pages that belong to shared libraries should be marked as memory mapped and should not be marked as anonymous. However, when I run pmap for any process, I find that there are some memory ranges that are backed by a file and yet they anonymous pages

```
     Address Perm   Offset Device    Inode   Size   Rss   Pss Shared_Clean Shared_Dirty Private_Clean Private_Dirty Referenced Anonymous AnonHugePages Swap KernelPageSize MMUPageSize Locked                   VmFlagsMapping
7f9677dca000 rw-p 0005b000  08:01 73931708      4     4     4            0            0             0             4          4         4             0    0              4           4      0    rd wr mr mw me ac sd  libibus-1.0.
so.5.0.505
```

So are pages belonging to shared libraries anonymous sometimes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text and read-only data in shared libraries are memory mapped files.  Libraries often have their own writable section (data and zero fill) which must be loaded per-process, writable, and can't be written back to the file.  These are anonymous after loading.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add to this. In most operating systems ALL user pages are backed by files:
1. Readonly pages of an executable or shared library
2. Files that are explicitly memory mapped
3. The page file.

I express the opinion that the Linux terminology of "anonymous pages" misleading.

Comment: But the "page file" is not a file as commonly understood. It is a device partition, from which page-sized blocks are allocated. "Anonymous" in this context means that there is no discrete identifiable path name associated with the mapping.

Comment: True in the current Linux and classical Unix systems. From the perspective of general operating system understanding in a world where modern operating systems (i.e. designed after 1975) do not rely on partitions for page files, it is confusing. I would imagine that contiguous files and, with it, dynamic page files are in the Linux development queue somewhere.